# Way to parse notifications

Tags: android, flutter, dart, notifications, upi

I am developing a budget tracker app as a college club project. In that i want to inculcate a feature of auto updating the app when a payment is made using UPI (Unified Payments Interface) .

For those who don't know UPI is a instant contactless payment system which enables users to directly deposit money into the sellers account by scanning a QR code custom to the sellers account.

So when money is debited from the account a notification is received by the customer saying
Money Transfer:Rs 25.00 from HDFC Bank A/c XXXXXX....
Format remains constant throughout any notification as it is auto generated ig .

So I want to parse said notification to auto detect the amount and log the amount in the budget

I am relatively new to app development and am just starting to learn flutter from this 6 month long project , previously had made a simple chatting app in Kotlin as a tutorial.

Tech Stacks planning to use : Flutter , HIVE(For managing the database on the users phone itself).

Would be really helpful if i could gain some direction or resources to achieve the above mentioned , any correction in tech stacks or any modification in original idea are accepted .

I am actually clueless and was looking for some direction.
I was first thinking about ways to obtain this data . Possible options were to periodically access bank statements but again no idea how to go about this (i figure the permissions will be highly restrictive and a big headache) . Then thought of this notification parsing . So that's it .....

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's a very broad question that's difficult to answer, but here's some things to get you started:

In a Flutter app, you can use `firebase_messaging` to capture and read the content of notifications that are received (by your app!)

Package:
https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging

Documentation:
https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/overview/

Concretely, there are callbacks that are invoked when a notification is received by your app, which you can listen to and handle by reading the title and body. (`onMessage` and `onBackgroundMessage`).

**Keep note however**, that your app can't just snoop around other apps' notifications! It'll only have access to notifications that are sent to the app itself (by your server).

Using a notification can still be preferable over polling the server repeatedly, but they won't work exactly the way you desire.

Comment: See for instance the responses under this Reddit post asking something similar in React Native: https://www.reddit.com/r/reactnative/comments/t6aqt5

Comment: there is one correction on my end tho , the users doesn't receive a notificaiton but rather he/she receives an SMS from the bank saying : 
Money Transfer:Rs 25.00 from HDFC Bank A/c XXXXXX.... 

so any way of accessing the messages with all the proper permissions(ofc!) ?

i know this may be sounding absurd .

Comment: That makes it a bit easier I think. There are a few packages like this one: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_sms_inbox that can query the SMS messages on your device, and filter them to find the one you're looking for. Android only though from what I can see

Comment: So only on android , nothing for IOS ... 
Thanks a lot for your help